# How to bind to compound property's component in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

There are some properties in `JavaFX` like [`boundsInParentProperty()`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/Node.html#boundsInParentProperty--) which is of type [`Bounds`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/geometry/Bounds.html). This class have several components, which are not observable.

So, what if I wish to bind to one of them?

For example to `Bounds#getMinX()`?

Do we have some `bind...` functions to extract component of a property? And may I be sure that the listeners will be notified on separate components change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Bindings.selectDouble` can be used to create this binding:

```
DoubleBinding minXBinding = Bindings.selectDouble(node.boundsInParentProperty(), "minX");
```

> And may I be sure that the listeners will be notified on separate components change?

Yes. Even though it's not documented that `Bounds` is immutable, by looking at the source code you can find out that:

- properties such as `minX` are stored in fields with `private` access.
- there are no write accesses to those fields except in the constructor.
- the getters for those properties are `final`.

Therefore `Bounds` is effectively immuteable and therefore you can be sure that the value of the property has to be replaced, if the bounds change.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the `boundsInParentProperty()` you can use `Bindings.createDoubleBinding`.

```
 DoubleBinding minXBinding = Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> boundsInParentProperty.get().getMinX(), boundsInParentProperty);

 DoubleProperty minX = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
 minX.bind(minXBinding);
```